# Loop PHP Url GET

Tags: php

I have a little problem and I can't see the solution. It should be very easy.
I want to make a liitle script that does a simle thing.
When I click:

Class -> go to classes.php?sort=class-desc

Then Class again -> go to classes.php?sort=class-asc

Then Class again -> go to classes.php?sort=class-desc

And so on ...

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
        $item = $_GET['sort'];

        $pos = strpos($item, '-');
        $crit = substr($item, 0, $pos);
        $ordine = substr($item, $pos+1);
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-asc>Class</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-asc>General</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=abscences-asc>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left;width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-asc>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";


            }else{        

                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-desc>Class</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-desc>General</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=absente-desc>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left;width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-desc>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";
            $item = 'avg_grades';                
        }
```

I'm sorry , I know It is an easy thing but I simply don't know where to put the loop.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to *visit* those webpages using PHP? Or are you trying to `echo` some links? Please explain.

Comment: what loop? also I think your question is missing part of your code

Comment: You just need another if else statement. When `$ordine` is `desc` do if otherwise else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `if else` statement to check your `$ordine` variable:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $item = $_GET['sort'];

    $sort = explode('-', $item);

    $crit = $sort[0];
    $ordine = $sort[1];

    if ($ordine === 'desc') {
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-asc>Class</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-asc>General</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=abscences-asc>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-asc>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-desc>Class</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-desc>General</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=absente-desc>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
        echo "<div style='float:left; width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-desc>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";
        $item = 'avg_grades';
    }
}
```

Or you could do it a bit shorter by applying the `$ordine` variable in your `a` tag `href`:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $item = $_GET['sort'];

    $sort = explode('-', $item);

    $crit = $sort[0];
    $ordine = $sort[1] === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';

    echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-$ordine>Class</a></div>";
    echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-$ordine>General</a></div>";
    echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=absente-$ordine>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
    echo "<div style='float:left; width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-$ordine>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet , i have removed the code duplication :

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
        $item = $_GET['sort'];
        $submitted_direction_exploded = explode('-',$item);
        $submitted_direction = isset($submitted_direction_exploded[1]) ? $submitted_direction_exploded[1] : '';  
        $direction = ($direction=='desc')?'asc' : $submitted_direction;  
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=class-$direction>Class</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=avg_grades-$direction>General</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left; width: 150px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=abscences-$direction>Nr Abscences</a></div>";
                echo "<div style='float:left;width: 180px;'><a href=classes.php?sort=nr_students-$direction>Nr Students</a></div><br><br>";

}
```